# Bash script gives psycopg2 error: symbol not found in flat namespace (_PQbackendPID)?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, bash, psycopg2

I am using Apple M1. Here is the bash script I wrote.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Open Activity Tracker website
python -m webbrowser http://127.0.0.1:8000/

# Activate virtual environment
. dj-env/bin/activate

# Navigate to Activity Tracker project folder
cd dj_activity_tracker

# Run Django local development server
python manage.py runserver
```

1. When you run manually are you doing that in the same virtualenv? Yes.
2. Are you doing the installs into the virtualenv? Yes.
3. What version of psycopg? Within my virtual environment, I run "pip show psycopg2-binary". It outputs "Version: 2.9.5".

When I run these commands on my terminal manually without the script, it works. However, when I use this script, I get the error:

```
File "/Users/doge/Desktop/dj-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 28, in \<module\>
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: dlopen(/Users/doge/Desktop/dj-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/\_psycopg.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace (\_PQbackendPID)
```

Things I have tried:

- Uninstall/reinstall psycopg2
- brew install postgresql

I am stumped on how this is working manually but not when I run the script. What could be the issue? I appreciate your support.

Comment: 1) When you run manually are you doing that in the same `virtualenv`? 2) Are you doing the installs into the `virtualenv`? 3) What version of `psycopg`? **Add information as update to question**.